# How can I model a process BPMN 2.0 in which the processflow depends on the role involved?

Tags: process, bpmn, business-process-management

We have specific process that concerns internal notifications. However, how the process goes depends on te person that receives the notification.

For example:
Admin can send the notification. But if role A receives it, only a confirmation of receiving the notification is enough. If role B is set as receiver, a confirmation and response is required and so on.

So different roles as receiver will have a different outcome. How can I model this through BPMN 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

When your send messages to two different receivers, there are already two different branches in your process. In one branch you send it to role A, in the other to role B. So it is easy to model the next steps in the branches.

Maybe you want to send it to both, and depending on which one reacts first, the other branch gets cancelled. This can be done by sending a signal that interrupts a sub process in the lane of the other branch.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you maybe share how you. would model it? So I can see an example.